# Jquery scroll problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have some uncommon wishes about scrolling in the page I'm making. I already tried a lot of things, but those aren't working like they should. All I want is that when people use their scroll wheel  (wherever their cursor stands) the search-results are scrolling.

I've uploaded my result so far at http://www.veylau.be/testzone/scrollfix/searchtwee.html
Just click the search button to see the dummy results.

Problems:

1) With the script I'm using now I'm having a sort of a parallax effect. I just want the results to scroll, not the rest of the page.

2) When the rest of the page is done scrolling, it isn't possible to scroll through anymore.

3) is it possible to catch the scroll-event when the cursor is over the #googleMap or the #mapContainer div? I tried like this, but only the second one is executing.

```
  $("#mapContainer").scroll(function(event){...});
  $(window).scroll(function(event){...});
```

Thank you very much for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `$(window).scroll(function(event){...});` and inside this function check if the mouse is `hover` the mapContainer with the check `if($("#mapContainer:hover").length>0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like tracking the mouse movement , and when scroll occurs setting the position to the last known position

I have tried a sample, Here is my code , Not perfectly refined. still i think this may help

```
var MouseposX;
var MouseposY;
$(window).bind("mousemove", function (event) {
    MouseposX = event.pageX;
    MouseposY = event.pageY;
});
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

placeDiv(MouseposX, MouseposY); 

});
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById('searchResults');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
}
```

Check the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/46WLt/3/